# Force div to scroll if the text overflows HTML/CSS?

Tags: css, html, scrollbar

So I have a div tag to sort of draw boxes around various sections, and of course make actual sections.

In one of the sections, there is more text than can be held in the div tag, so I want to for the text within the div tag to have a scroll bar to make it so the text doesn't overflow outside of the box.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the following:

```
div {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

If you want them to scroll only in one direction, you can use the `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` properties.

Answer (score 23):

Add `width` and `height` CSS properties to the `div`, as well as `overflow:auto`

If you add `overlow:scroll`, the scroll bars will be always visible.

If you want to have only horizontal scroll, add `white-space:nowrap` to the element inside of the `div`.